# Can't boot after installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my notebook

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my notebook but I can't boot.
The status is a black screen and no key works.

Strangely, I can boot the Ubuntu as a next method:

- Plug USB stick (install program)
- Boot sequence changes (HDD → USB)
- USB lamp blinks and stops
- Booting from HDD

Why can't I boot without USB stick?

Comment: Do you have Windows installed? If so, how did you install Ubuntu? Need more details.

Comment: No. I didn't install Windows. I just installed ubuntu from the live cd(usb stick).

Comment: I solved. :) I installed auto mode for many times. but, I did not still able to boot.. so, i installed manual mode(partition settings) and was able to boot!! i don't know why..(ubuntu bug????) :(

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have your bootloader installed on the USB-stick.

When either boot into ubuntu with the boot stick and reinstall grub to the correct partition/drive or reinstall ubuntu making sure to point the installer to the correct partion/drive in the step where you configure your partition setup. You may have to go into the customize menu to do this.

youll want something like:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
```

where sdx is your primary partition on the drive your bios tries to boot

Comment: thanks. but, the error display. ( error:will not proceed with blocklists.)

Comment: I assume your getting that error when your try to run grub-install? what is your sdx? sda?

Comment: I execute "sudo grub-install /dev/sda". but, I solved it like above comment of question. but, I don't know why. :( . anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: sometimes it just likes to be a pain =)